# Use computed model property in a controller other then its own with ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

So having issues using a computed property in a different controller than its default.

I have this model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    firstName:       DS.attr('string'),
    lastName:        DS.attr('string'),
    email:           DS.attr('string'),
    emailOptIn:      DS.attr('boolean'),
    emailVerified:   DS.attr('boolean'),
    receivedWelcome: DS.attr('boolean'),

    locations:            DS.hasMany('location'),
    serviceRelationships: DS.hasMany('service-relationship'),
    phoneNumbers:         DS.hasMany('phone-number'),

    fullName: function(){
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

Which is in `contact.js` (we are using the ember-cli).

Then I have this controller:

```
var NavBarController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    fullName: '',
    init: function(){
        var contactId = this.session.contactId;
        var self = this;
        this.store.find('contact', contactId).then(function(contact){
            self.set('fullName', contact.get('fullName'));
        });
})

export default NavBarController;
```

Which doesn't render anything in the template. However if I change it to:

```
    fullName: '',
    init: function(){
        var contactId = this.session.contactId;
        var self = this;
        this.store.find('contact', contactId).then(function(contact){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                self.set('fullName', contact.get('fullName'));
            }, 100);
        });
})
```

Then it renders the `{{fullName}}` handlebar just fine.

***QUESTION:*** Why is it not resolving in the `then` function without the `timeout`?

Comment: May you write a http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ reproducing your case?. As I can see your alias property must point to the controller content contact: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.contacts.content") and check that the App.ContactsController which could be renamed to App.ContactController should be a ObjectController whose content property must be loaded.